# Combining text in list comprehension

Tags: haskell

Using 
`cats :: Integer -> String`

How do I display 
`> cats 5`

Will show

```
cats
cats cats
cats cats cats
cats cats cats cats
cats cats cats cats cats
```

I've tried a single line and multi-line output

`cat n = concat["cat\n" | n <- [0..n-1]]`
and
`cat_row n = concat["cat " | m <- [0..n-1], m < n]`

but I'm not sure how to combine them.

Comment: It is easiest to solve this problem in two stages. First, write a function `catsLine :: Integer -> String`` which makes one line containing `n` repetitions of “cats”. (You’ve done this already with your first attempt — try replacing `\n` with a space.) Next, write your function `cats :: Integer -> String` by running `catsLine` for 1,2,3,…,_n_ repetitions, then `concat`ing them together. I won’t give an answer directly as this looks like homework and I want you to work it out for yourself. (Even if it isn’t homework, it’s always best to work it out yourself!)

Comment: @bradrn yes, it's for my homework. I figured it out! Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome @IzzudinAnaur! Even though it may not strictly qualify, can I add my instructions as an answer?

Comment: Why not use something like `replicate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a solution for single rows:

```
cat_row n = concat["cat " | m <- [0..n-1], m < n]
```

(by the way, the last `m < n` is redundant, since it's always true)

So, you can iterate over that in the same way:

```
cat n = concat[cat_row m ++ "\n" | m <- [1..n]]
```

For a simpler solution, you could exploit the library functions `unlines` and `unwords`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with pattern matching over `Integer`

```
cats :: Integer -> String
cats 0 = ""
cats n = aux 1 n
  where
    aux m 0 = ""
    aux m n = concat (fcats m) ++ aux (m+1) (n-1)
    fcats n = take (fromIntegral n) (repeat "cats ") ++ ["\n"]
```

I used an aux function to put it in reverse, if not, it would be five cats first and last one cats

Answer (score 0):

Since this is from your homework, you should also consider explicit recursive solutions.

If we look at your example where cats 5 have returned 5 rows, we will notice that rows 2-5 contains cats 4. More precisely, if we disregard the left-most column what remains is exactly cats 4.

So, if given cats 4, we just need to add the left-most column to get cats 5. If the rows are represented as a list of strings, this amounts to prepending "cats " to each of the strings and add a first one. Let's write a help function that works like this:

```
help :: String -> Int -> [String]
help s 1 = [s ++ " "]
help s n = [s ++ " " ++ x | x <- "" : help s (n-1)]
```

The call

```
> help "cats" 5
```

then results in

```
["cats ","cats cats ","cats cats cats ","cats cats cats cats ","cats cats cats cats cats "]
```

Not exactly what we want but almost. Ending newlines are missing and it's not a single string ready to print. Appending newlines is easy with another list comprehension:

```
[ x ++ "\n" | x <- help "cats" 5]
```

This gives us

```
["cats \n","cats cats \n","cats cats cats \n","cats cats cats cats \n","cats cats cats cats cats \n"]
```

The last remaining step is to turn this list of strings into a string by concatenating the substrings. Since a string is a list of Char, a list of strings is really just a list of list of Char. This means we can concatenate all substrings by picking out the characters one at a time in order and form the result from them:

```
[c | s <- [ x ++ "\n" | x <- help "cats" 5], c <- s]
```

Note how we first pick out (generate) substrings s, and for each such we pick out its characters c. This now gives us the desired result:

```
"cats \ncats cats \ncats cats cats \ncats cats cats cats \ncats cats cats cats cats \n"
```

To recap, this alternative solution relies on explicit recursion and list comprehensions. It does not rely on predefined functions. Instead of using list comprehensions, we could have written short primitive recursive functions, effectively getting a highly self-contained program.

Again, since this is homework, I suggest these two exercises to you:

1. Put the pieces above together into a function cats :: Int -> String.
2. Rewrite the code so it no longer makes use of list comprehensions.

Happy Haskelling!